# Derivation of Least Squares / Associativity of vector multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, associativity

I tried to solve Linear Least Squares and I am kind of stuck / confused about the property of vector multiplication/associativity/commutativity.

The way I defined my problem is the following: Let $\phi(x_n)$ define the features of data point $x_n$ with $\phi(x_n),w \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$. Then the loss is given by
$$
 L = \frac{1}{2} \sum^N _{n=1} (\phi(x_n)^Tw -y_n)^2
$$

I took the derivative w.r.t $w$, set it to 0 and got

$$
 0 =  \frac{1}{2} \sum^N _{n=1} (\phi(x_n)^Tw)^2 - 2\phi(x_n)^Twy_n + y_n ^2
$$

$$
 0 =  \sum^N _{n=1} (\phi(x_n)^Tw)\phi(x_n) - \phi(x_n)^Ty_n \rightarrow 
\sum^N _{n=1} \phi(x_n)^Ty_n = \sum^N _{n=1} (\phi(x_n)^Tw)\phi(x_n)
$$
The term $\sum^N _{n=1} (\phi(x_n)^Tw)\phi(x_n)$ confuses me. For one, it is not associative, but the multiplication is still defined because $\phi(x_n)^Tw$ is a scalar. Also, if I would write  $(\phi(x_n)^Tw)\phi(x_n) = \phi(x_n) (\phi(x_n)^Tw)$ then turns turns out to be the correct solution for least squares if I can use associativity, i.e. $ (\phi(x_n) (\phi(x_n)^T)w$  . This would make sense to me since scalar multiplication is commutative. But why would I be allowed to use associativity now and not before ? Also, if I could look at $\phi(x_n)^Tw$ as a "unit" which is a scalar, then it must also hold that $(\phi(x_n)^Tw )^T = w ^T \phi(x_n)$, which is again not associative with $\phi(x_n)$.

So, I guess, my question is: Where is the mistake in my derivation/my line of thinking? Im pretty sure it has something to do with the fact that the first expression is a 1x1 matrix and I look at it as a scalar, but Im very confused about the entire situation, especially when I am allowed to use commutativity and when I can use associativity.

Comment: Using column and row vectors gives the dot product $x\cdot y$ as a *matrix product* $x^Ty$, and matrix multiplication *is* associative.

Comment: @Berci So what you are saying is that my derivation is correct and that I can exchange the parentheses if the resulting operations are defined?

Comment: Yes, if the matrix product makes sense, then you can use associativity. Note that a column vector can only be multiplied from the right by an $1\times 1$ matrix.

Comment: Okay cool, thanks a lot!